# Function with two template overloads

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a template function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline void myFunction(T variable);
```

Now I want an overload/specialization for the case T is actually an std vector. So I also have

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline void myFunction(std::vector<T> variable)
```

It doens't give me any compile time or runtime warnings or errors but I'm worried that it might give undefined behavior. Could somebody tell me whether this would be okay?

Comment: Your code is completely fine. No UB. At least not in the sample you provided.

Comment: The standard library [does this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max). So rest assured.

Comment: It is an **overload**, not a **specialization** BTW.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I would say the std::max is slightly different than my situation as two arguments (a and b) are replaced with one argument (the initializer list) so the function signature is really different. I my case the signature is both with one argument and basically the second function argument type would also fit in the first function. That is not directly the case for std::max. But I get the idea. Maybe the std::max is not the correct example ;)

Comment: @C.Binair - Your case is only "different" in so much as you overthink it. Function templates can be overloaded. Nothing more to it. You don't get undefined behavior from that, just overload resolution/parital ordering failure.

Comment: operators (as `operator <<`) would be another example then (as number of argument is fixed :-) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could somebody tell me whether this would be okay?

Yes, it is perfectly fine, no UB.

In general, overloading is not something that triggers UB on its own.

Comment: *"Hidden"* overloads might break ODR in some cases. but it is most ill-formed program than UB.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Maybe a small suggestion for both of you. Don't use abbreviations without introducing them. UB I assume stands for undefined behavior. ODR I have no clue what it would mean so I actually had to google (if I found the right one, it means one definition rule)

Comment: @C.Binair You're welcome! UB is a very well-known abbreviation in C, C++, Rust, etc. I used it because since you already mentioned undefined behavior in the question, so I thought it was clear. ODR is indeed the one definition rule, and it is also a very important rule in C++. I suggest you take a look at a glossary of terms if you want to program in C++ and read other answers in StackOverflow! :)